# how to make placeholder font (in form) sizes the same across devices?

Tags: html, css, forms

Using the below CSS, I have managed to get the placeholder font size to be similar for all common android browsers, but iphone's browser makes the placeholder font so tiny it's barely readable. If I increase the size so that it is readable, it becomes so huge on all other android browsers that it won't even fit in the form boxes (and looks ridiculous as it is larger than even the header font).

Is there a workaround to change the font size for just safari browsers? This massive disparity in font size is absurd, and I can't even find a compromise between the two where both are readable. [cbtemail.com](http://cbtemail.com) is the site if you want to see it.

```
input {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: #CCC;
    color: #000;
    height: 60px;
    font-size:28px
}
textarea {
    background-color: #ccc;
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    height: 90px;
    font-size:12px
}
::placeholder { /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
  color: #555;
  opacity: 1; /* Firefox */
  font-size: 28px;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    font-size: 18px;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
  color: #555;
}

::-ms-input-placeholder { /* Microsoft Edge */
  color: #555;
}
:-moz-placeholder {
    font-size: 28px;
}
::-moz-placeholder {
    font-size: 28px;
}
```

Comment: Update your css into '::-webkit-input-placeholder' and try accordingly. It should work.

Comment: That is the problem. When I make the font-size greater than 16px, it becomes enormous on samsung internet and chrome (android), but if I go less than 18px it becomes tiny on iphone safari. This is why '::-webkit-input-placeholder' is currently at 18px.